# How to fix error: The method put(Integer, Integer) in the type Map<Integer,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (int, String)

Tags: java, hashmap

I don't know how to fix this. I want to intake a certain number of strings with a hashmap. I am still a beginner coder and just learned hashmap. PLS help.

```
public class Hashmap {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lines = Scanner.nextInt();
    Map<Integer, Integer> hash = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        hash.put(i, Scanner.next());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Currently your map uses integers for both the key and the value. Was that your intention? If so, what would you expect the value to be if someone entered "xyz"?

Comment: I want to insert "xyz" at the 'i' place in the hashmap

Comment: And what *integer* value do you believe "xyz" to be?

Comment: If you want to store strings in the hashmap, you might want to define it as `Map<Integer, String> hash = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner.next` returns a `String` object. You cannot put a `String` as the value in a map you declared as taking `Integer` objects for values. Square peg, round hole.

You have a choice of three ways to fix.

You could change your map declaration to take `String` objects as the value. Change this:

```
Map< Integer , Integer > map = new HashMap<>();
```

… to:

```
Map< Integer , String > map = new HashMap<>();
```

Or, you can collect integers from the Scanner rather than text. Call [`Scanner#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()).

Or, you can collect text from the scanner, and then transform that text to an integer. Call [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)).